# what is wrog with this basic if code for finding the smallest number writen

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
       float A,B,C;
    printf("pls write a 3 numbers\n");
      scanf("%f%f%f",&A,&B,&C);
    if (%f<(%f||%f),A,B,C)
    {printf("NO A");}
            else if(%f<(%f||%f),B,C,A)

    {printf("NO C");}
    else if (%f<(%f||%f),C,B,A)
   { printf("NO B");}
    return 0;
}
```

i cant fix this code i dont know why its working proably it has a very easy solution but i am a beginner.some thing wrong wit if things i cant fix them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the error you get.

Comment: The first thing that is wrong in your code is the poor formatting. First format your code correctly, then we can talk about your actual problem. And also start reading your C text book, especially read about the `,` operator. It does not do what you think it does. And `if (%f<(%f||%f),A,B,C)` is total nonsense.

Comment: you should read a book from the beginning instead of just reading some snippets on the internet and inventing the syntax

Comment: @Jabberwocky username checks out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (%f<(%f||%f),A,B,C)
```

This is not the correct syntax to compare numbers. In fact you can only compare 2 numbers with a single operator.

To compare 3 numbers you need

```
if (A>B)
{
    if (A>C)
    {
        printf("no A");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no C");
    }
}
else
{
    if (B>C)
    {
        printf("no B");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no C");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used % symbol in the conditional statement. %f is a format specifier which is used to define the type of data (float here) to be taken from the **standard input**. That's why it is only used in scanf(). main() is a built-in function. You shouldn't define anything there! Hope the below code helps you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
float a,b,c;
printf("Enter three numbers");
scanf("%f %f %f",&a,&b,&c);
if((a>b) && (a>c)) 
printf("\n a is greater");
else if(b>c) 
printf("\n b is greater");
else 
printf("\n c is greater"); // if the above doesn't work, automatically c is greater.
getch(); //get the output directly
}
```

Comment: i can not rate yet but thanks to all it realy helped thanks